# Emitting socket.io events from express router and processing on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to build a webchat app using node.js and express.  I have a router file and a server file, together with some client files. I would like to emit a join event from the router and processing it on the server so the user can join the room. I did i like this

**Server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const layout = require('express-layout');
const app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(server);
const routes = require('./router')(io);
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require("fs");



app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const middleware = [
    layout(),
    express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')),
    bodyParser.urlencoded(),

];

app.use(middleware);

app.use('/', routes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!");
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});



io.on('connect', onConnect);

function onConnect(socket) {
    var contents = fs.readFileSync("./public/rooms.json");
    let rooms = JSON.parse(contents);
    socket.emit('parse',rooms);
    socket.on('join',function (name, room) {
        console.log(name+" "+ room);
        socket.join(room);
        socket.user=name;
        socket.room=room;
    })
}
```

Here I just initialize the io connection together with all the dependencies I use. I use `const routes = require('./router')(io);` to pass the io variable

**router.js**

```
    const express = require('express');
    const User= require("./public/classes/User");
    const router = express.Router();
    const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator');
    const {matchedData} = require('express-validator/filter');

    var userlist=new Array();


    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.render('index', {
            data: {},
            errors: {}
        })
    });

    router.post('/enter', [
        check('username')
            .isLength({min: 1})
            .withMessage('Username is required').trim()   //implement personalized check
    ], (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.render('index', {
                data: req.body,
                errors: errors.mapped()
            })
        }
        const data = matchedData(req)
        handleJoin(data);
    });
    return router;





    //MOVE TO SUPPORT
    function find(name) {
        return 1;
    }

    function handleJoin (data){
        if(find(data.username)){
            const newUser= new User (data.username, data.room,"");
            userlist.push(newUser);
            io.emit('join',newUser.name,newUser.room);
        }
    };
};
```

The console should log the name and the choosen room but it doesn't. How do I process this?